# sending image in byte array(JSON) from server,and retrieve in android and store in sqlite and display in listview containing textview and imageview

Tags: android, json, sqlite, listview, imageview

Using REST API I am generating image in byte array.

```
@Column(name = "image")
        private byte[] image;
```

In android application I want to use the JSON and store in sqlite, and also display in Composite ListView consisting of TextView and ImageView.
This is the json which i am getting.
   "image":"LzlqLzRBQVFTa1pKUmdBQkFRRUFZQUJnQUFELzRR...."

Answer (score 1):

Store the `JSON` in SQLite, while fetching use getBlob(). For displaying use BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray.

```
 Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(android.util.Base64.decode(cursor.getBlob(),0,cursor.getBlob().length);
                im.setImageBitmap(bm);
```